# Is there a way to trigger a shell command automatically after repository update/switch?

Tags: svn, git, repository

I would like to perform a shell command that takes care of cache files and compilation after I have run `git pull` or `svn update` (in another project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *SVN hooks* from command line, on various events(pre- and post-) to run your custom scripts.

It appears that there is no hook for 'update' event, please see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) and gather details.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is not a "GUI layer over core SVN".  TortoiseSVN is an independently-developed app that leverages the published SVN libraries.  It implements several features which are not in SVN.EXE, such as client-side hook scripts (one example).  SVN hooks are server-side.  They do not run when a user does SVN UPDATE on their local working copy.

Comment: "if the GUI supports, command-line has to!" -- who made that rule?

Comment: That's generally the case in Linux. In this case it's not really applicable though.

Comment: Ok, I tried to delete this answer, it says I can't delete an accepted answer. I'll try to modify it instead.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding SVN:  not sure if this will help, but if you use TortoiseSVN, you can use client-side hook scripts:

There are currently six types of hook scripts available

Start-commit
Called before the commit dialog is shown. You might want to use this if the hook modifies a versioned file and affects the list of files that need to be committed and/or commit message. However you should note that because the hook is called at an early stage, the full list of objects selected for commit is not available.

Pre-commit
Called after the user clicks OK in the commit dialog, and before the actual commit begins. This hook has a list of exactly what will be committed.

Post-commit
Called after the commit finishes (whether successful or not).

Start-update
Called before the update-to-revision dialog is shown.

Pre-update
Called before the actual Subversion update begins.

Post-update
Called after the update finishes (whether successful or not).

A hook is defined for a particular working copy path. You only need to specify the top level path; if you perform an operation in a sub-folder, TortoiseSVN will automatically search upwards for a matching path.

Next you must specify the command line to execute, starting with the path to the hook script or executable. This could be a batch file, an executable file or any other file which has a valid windows file association, eg. a perl script.

Comment: I run the update/pull commands the server via SSH and do not use TortoiseSVN -- I would need a remote desktop for that to work.